# Why do the browsers in different viewports keep hiding content that i only want to hide for certain viewport sizes?

Tags: html, css

I've only included the HTML codes for "main" as this is the part that i want to be able to control with media query. I would like the content to only be viewable on viewports smaller than 480px but the browser seems to hide the content on all viewport sizes.

CSS media query code below:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {

                                             main { display:none;}

                                          }
```

}
HTML codes below. The class "paragraph" are just rules for alignment and font, so I didn't include them here. The opening and closing `<main> </main>` tags arent shown below, just their content

`

```
<p class="paragraph">

    Durango Jewelry and Gem Shop pampers you with one-of-a-kind, high quality wire-wrapped pendants and gems. Our works of art are inspired by natural<br>
    geometries and the vast beauty of mother nature.<br>





</p>


<p class="paragraph"> 


    <br>The featured pendant provides these characteristics :<br><br>


        <ul class="paragraph">

            <li class="listing"> <span style="color:red;">"Smoky Quartz"</span> gemstones, also called <span style="color:red;">"Soulmate Crystal"</span>  </li><br>
            <li class="listing"> gemstone is over 2 carats </li><br>
            <li class="listing"> high quality silver alloy requires very little polishing </li><br>



        </ul><br>


</p>


<p class="paragraph">

    Come over to our store !


</p>
```

}

Comment: Make sure you have this in <head> section: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: @Ernie It works now! I didn't have that in my html file previously. thanks!

Comment: No problem, it happens! Make sure you always add that to all your Html files. I actually once spent almost an hour dealing with this which is why I had a feeling this was the issue haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have this in `<head>` section: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

**Explanation:** Media queries do not work without this meta tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code will help and you can visi Mozilla developers page to get more insight
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media

```
@media (min-width: 481px) {
     main { display:none;}
}
```

Comment: You did it backwards, he wants the content hidden on devices wider than 481px. So it would actually be ```min-width: 481px```

Comment: Thanks I appreciate... I think now it will be okay

Comment: @GozbethStanslaus @Matthew T i tried, it didn't work. Inserting `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` as suggested by @Ernie did the trick.